# Sorting of numbers with special characters in different column values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I have an HTML table and have eight columns with values separated by commas, decimal points etc.And some are percentage values and hour values.How to sort the values in descending order in the first click and in ascending order in the second click while clicking on corresponding column headers.

The code i tried to sort is as shown:

```js
function getVal(elm, n) {
      var v = $(elm).find('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
      var num = v.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
      num = parseFloat(num);
      if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
        v = parseInt(num, 10);
      }
      return v;
    }

    var f = 1;
    $(".table-sortable .column-head").find('span').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      table = $(this).closest('table');
      th = $(this).parent();
      $(th).find('span').toggleClass('rotate');

      f *= -1;
      var n = th.prevAll().length;
      console.log(n);
      var rows = table.find('tbody  tr').get();
      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var A = getVal(a, n);
        var B = getVal(b, n);
        if (A < B) {
          return -1 * f;
        }
        if (A > B) {
          return 1 * f;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        table.children('tbody').append(row);
      });
    });
```

The HTML table:

```html
<table class="table-sortable" id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc1</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc2</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc3</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc4</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc5</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc6</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc7</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc8</span></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="table-body">
      <tr class="table-row">
         <td scope="row" class="column-fixed">BU001</td>
         <td class="column-values">18.240.00h</td>
         <td class="column-values">200h</td>
         <td class="column-values">46,13%</td>
         <td class="column-values">12.600.00€</td>
         <td class="column-values">77,00%</td>
         <td class="column-values">43.10%</td>
         <td class="column-values-end">2.82%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <td scope="row" class="column-fixed">AU003</td>
        <td class="column-values">21.240.00h</td>
        <td class="column-values">120h</td>
        <td class="column-values">1,13%</td>
        <td class="column-values">4.600.00€</td>
        <td class="column-values">12,00%</td>
        <td class="column-values">66.10%</td>
        <td class="column-values-end">1.82%</td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="table-row">
         <td class="column-fixed">AU309</td>
         <td class="column-values">2.240.00h</td>
         <td class="column-values">200h</td>
         <td class="column-values">26,13%</td>
         <td class="column-values">59.600.00€</td>
         <td class="column-values">3,00%</td>
         <td class="column-values">40.10%</td>
         <td class="column-values-end">12.82%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-row">
         <td class="column-fixed">DT907</td>
         <td class="column-values">12.240.00h</td>
         <td class="column-values">100h</td>
         <td class="column-values">6,13%</td>
         <td class="column-values">49.600.00€</td>
         <td class="column-values">90,00%</td>
         <td class="column-values">4.10%</td>
         <td class="column-values-end">2.82%</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have a great jquery plug-in for that : [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Any way to edit the code that I have tried to sort.And so that I can sort easily

Comment: Any way to get help?

Comment: What is the issue ? Your code seems to work when I test it in a snippet

Comment: please run code snippet now.While clicking on header its not getting sorted

Comment: ok. I think you just forget to include jquery library. I post an answer just to show that it works...

Answer (score 0):

don't forget jquery !

```js
function getVal(elm, n) {
      var v = $(elm).find('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
      //var num=(n!==0)? v.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, ''):v;
      var num = v.match(/^\d/)?v.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, ''):v;
      
      num = parseFloat(num);
      if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
        v = parseInt(num, 10);
      }
      return v;
    }

    var f = 1;
    $(".table-sortable .column-head").find('span').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      table = $(this).closest('table');
      th = $(this).parent();
      $(th).find('span').toggleClass('rotate');

      f *= -1;
      var n = th.prevAll().length;
      console.log(n);
      var rows = table.find('tbody  tr').get();
      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var A = getVal(a, n);
        var B = getVal(b, n);
        if (A < B) {
          return -1 * f;
        }
        if (A > B) {
          return 1 * f;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        table.children('tbody').append(row);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-sortable" id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc1</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc2</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc3</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc4</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc5</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc6</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc7</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="column-head"><span>abc8</span></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="table-body">
      <tr class="table-row">
         <td scope="row" class="column-fixed">AU201</td>
         <td class="column-values">18.240.00h</td>
         <td class="column-values">200h</td>
         <td class="column-values">46,13%</td>
         <td class="column-values">12.600.00€</td>
         <td class="column-values">77,00%</td>
         <td class="column-values">43.10%</td>
         <td class="column-values-end">2.82%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-row">
        <td scope="row" class="column-fixed">BU004</td>
        <td class="column-values">21.240.00h</td>
        <td class="column-values">120h</td>
        <td class="column-values">1,13%</td>
        <td class="column-values">4.600.00€</td>
        <td class="column-values">12,00%</td>
        <td class="column-values">66.10%</td>
        <td class="column-values-end">1.82%</td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="table-row">
         <td class="column-fixed">AZ455</td>
         <td class="column-values">2.240.00h</td>
         <td class="column-values">200h</td>
         <td class="column-values">26,13%</td>
         <td class="column-values">59.600.00€</td>
         <td class="column-values">3,00%</td>
         <td class="column-values">40.10%</td>
         <td class="column-values-end">12.82%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-row">
         <td class="column-fixed">FE45</td>
         <td class="column-values">12.240.00h</td>
         <td class="column-values">100h</td>
         <td class="column-values">6,13%</td>
         <td class="column-values">49.600.00€</td>
         <td class="column-values">90,00%</td>
         <td class="column-values">4.10%</td>
         <td class="column-values-end">2.82%</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Numbers with special characters are getting sorted fine.And now  I edited the values of the first column.And I want to sort those values according to the alphabets and not according to numbers at the right side of the value.Now its got sorted according to numbers.

Comment: Any way to get help?

Comment: in your function getVal, you replace all non digit with nothing. So for your first column, it compares the numeric values at the end of the string. If it only occurs on the first column, you can modify your code in getVal : `var num=(n!==0)?v.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, ''):v;`or if you encounter this case on other columns, just check if the value begins with a digit or no : `var num = (v.match(/^\d/))?  v.split(/ /)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, ''):v;`